# Windows XP SP3 will not go into standby when Magic Jack is running

Tags: windows-xp, windows-media-center, shutdown, sp3, standby

When I select Start->Turn off computer->Standby the 'turn off computer' option window closes, and then nothing else happens.  I can start new applications, and Windows acts like I never selected standby.  If I have a TV program scheduled to record I get a window asking if I'm sure, there are programs scheduled to record - and the computer just keeps running after I select yes.  (If a program is not scheduled then that task in not running/in memory - this problem happens even if I'm not watching TV and no TV scheduling task is running.)  This problem happens regardless of whether Media Center is running.

Windows XP SP3 Media Center Edition, all current updates installed.

---

Update: I looked at "How to troubleshoot hibernation and standby issues in Windows XP" http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907477
ACPI is enabled, and "standby" is an option in "Power Options Properties."

Also, I used the computer for several hours after selecting standby (nothing happened) with no problems, before finally turning it off for the night.

Comment: Sundays are quiet.  Delete this question, then ask again on a weekday, and you might get more answers.

Comment: @Robert - please don't deface your posts like that.  that isn't useful.  instead, flag for moderator attention and request it be migrated/deleted/whatever.

Comment: What is wrong with the question that you want it deleted?

Comment: @quack, and random, do you guys really not see the comment that SLaks left? **That** is why Carl defaced his question and asked for it to be deleted.

Comment: @Carl, what does magicJack have to do with TV? And yes, power-management will not engage while most media-players are running; that’s by design (on the part of the media-player) because you would be really frustrated if the system suddenly shut down while you were watching a movie (and thus not moved the mouse or pressed a key in a while).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this.  If I kill MagicJack (internet phone) from the Task Manager the computer goes into standby.

Comment: What’s wrong with just exiting it normally?

Answer (score 1):

Easier solution, is to allow the MagicJack to sleep with the following commands

as administrator

```
C>powercfg -REQUESTSOVERRIDE PROCESS magicJack.exe DISPLAY SYSTEM
```

afterwards you can check it as follows:

```
C>powercfg -REQUESTSOVERRIDE
[SERVICE]

[PROCESS]
magicJack.exe DISPLAY SYSTEM

[DRIVER]
```

Comment: I’ll have to try that. The VLC devs have yet to change it so that it stops blocking the power-management functions when you pause, so this may be a work-around.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Magic Jacks for years on laptops and desktops and solved the Windows XP problem you presented by clicking the X at the top right side of Majic Jack screen. A new screen appears immediately and states "You are disconnecting Magic Jack, you will not be able to receive or make telephone calls. Do you want to do this?" After Magic Jack shuts down your computer will now hibernate, standby or shut down depending on your choice.  There is always a problem when you restart the computer or bring it out of hibernation with Majic Jack left plugged in because it interferes with the start up of Wi-Fi and slows the start up of other computer programs. The solution is JUST UNPLUG the Magic Jack before hibernating or shutting down. After restarting your computer just plug it back in and it will reload itself with no problem.

With Windows 7 I have not experienced a problem with hibernation, sleeping or shutting down the computer without closing Magic Jack.